# Typesetting long index entries in a nice way?

Tags: indexing, typography

I'm in the process of finalizing ma thesis and while checking the index I have seen what looks like a really bad typesetting result: the last entry in the right column of the first page of the index (*labelled weighted compatibility problem*) is too long for a single line, and thus LaTeX hyphenates it into *labelled weighted compatibility prob-lem* putting the `-lem` in a line of its own.

You can see the result in the following image:

[image: Picture showing the bottom of the index page, where on the right the last line contains only "lem, 48" right aligned]

The final result looks really bad (at least to me), and I'd like to know how could I fix it. For example I'd much prefer if LaTeX simply placed the whole word *problem* in that line, instead of hyphenating it, or maybe reduce the indent space? Does anybody know of any options to make that entry look good?

The problem can be reproduced with the following document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

This is it\index{a very very very very very very very very long index entry}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

---

I'm using the `makeidx` package, not `imakeidx`.

Comment: You could put the part that you want to keep together in an `\mbox`, like `This is it\index{a very very very very very very very very long \mbox{index entry}}.`

Comment: @PietvanOostrum I tried it and it produces a very weird output. Instead of `labelled weighted compatibility prob-<newline>lem` it produces `x problem` where I put `\mbox{problem}` to avoid hyphenating it...

Comment: Very strange. With your document above, and the index entries as in @egreg's answer I don't get any problem, with or without the `\mbox`. Your setup must be different, because even without `\mbox` I don't get hyphenation.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum Okay, I believe the issue is that I'm using the `makeidx` package and not `imakeidx`; I thought otherwise. Changing the `\usepackage` lines gives some errors, so I'll have to see where the compatibility is breaking...

Comment: OK, with `\usepackage{makeidx}` I see the hyphenation. But then with `\mbox{problem}` it disappears.

Comment: Putting `\raggedright` before `\printindex` also helps.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot reproduce the problem. Anyway, it might make sense, in your case with long index entries, to disable hyphenation altogether:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex
\indexsetup{othercode={\hyphenpenalty=10000 }}

\begin{document}

text

\index{current action type preserving}
\index{current action types}
\index{current activities}
\index{labelled transition system}
\index{labelled weighted compatibility problem}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: disabling hyphenation altogether will usually help, but what if one is dealing with horrendous chemical names?  some of those may be longer than the available width of an entry in a two-column format.

Comment: @barbarabeeton In Italy we have a saying that can be translated into “wanting a full wine barrel and a drunken wife”. `;-)`